# Getting ‘We’re sorry, but something went wrong.’ error when I try to reset a password for a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I just completed my OMR course and was just testing to see if everything is working well and noticed the function to reset your password gets me the following errors.

This is the path: 
https://ants-omr-pinteresting.herokuapp.com/users/password

And I get prompt which states 'We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.'

Here is my github repository https://github.com/antonioOrtiz/pinteresting

Below is the output from my 'heroku logs' and this is a link do the output on [dropbox.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n3vxosc63pnp7k5/heoku_logs.png?dl=0)

```
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484003+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483958+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483962+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483972+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483980+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483991+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484007+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483973+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483988+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484006+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483976+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483977+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483986+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483989+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483994+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483983+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483996+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483999+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483961+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483992+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483997+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484002+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484011+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483975+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484037+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483964+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484010+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484004+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484009+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.483985+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484013+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484038+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484040+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484042+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484043+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484045+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484046+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484048+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484049+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484057+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484051+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484059+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484060+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484062+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484063+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484065+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484066+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484068+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484069+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484072+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484071+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484074+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484076+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484077+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484079+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484080+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484082+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484083+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484085+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484087+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484088+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484090+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484091+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484093+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484094+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484096+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484097+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484099+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-18T17:37:38.484100+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-18T17:37:38.727934+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ants-omr-pinteresting.herokuapp.com request_id=6f9956f6-0a71-431f-939a-a3b7e64b140f fwd="72.229.172.196" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-07-18T17:37:27.116178+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2015-07-18T17:37:27.116465+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2015-07-18T17:41:31.276531+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/users/password" host=ants-omr-pinteresting.herokuapp.com request_id=f0c9e48a-b368-4b83-89c6-5d2c8c542b66 fwd="54.87.18.234" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=265
2015-07-18T17:41:31.266318+00:00 app[web.1]: Started HEAD "/users/password" for 54.87.18.234 at 2015-07-18 17:41:31 +0000
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269738+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269742+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/users/password"):
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269745+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269747+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269749+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269752+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269755+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269750+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269754+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269757+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269759+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269761+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269764+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269766+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269768+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269769+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269771+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269772+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269774+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269777+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269778+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269780+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269781+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-18T17:41:31.269783+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

**update**

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
                    pins GET    /pins(.:format)                pins#index
                         POST   /pins(.:format)                pins#create
                 new_pin GET    /pins/new(.:format)            pins#new
                edit_pin GET    /pins/:id/edit(.:format)       pins#edit
                     pin GET    /pins/:id(.:format)            pins#show
                         PATCH  /pins/:id(.:format)            pins#update
                         PUT    /pins/:id(.:format)            pins#update
                         DELETE /pins/:id(.:format)            pins#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                    root GET    /                              pins#index
                   about GET    /about(.:format)               pages#about
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas! How'd you do that?

Comment: What's the output of "rake routes"?

Comment: `HEAD` request? Odd. What's even more odd is that I can't find any reference of making such request. And just so you know, you have some [unresolved git conflicts](https://github.com/antonioOrtiz/pinteresting/blob/master/pinteresting.sublime-workspace).

Comment: Added the output of the rake routes above...

Answer (score 1):

From logs you can know there is no route matches

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/users/password"):`

Try running `rake routes` and check if that `route` is present or not.

Comment: Thanks! Is this one specifically related? `user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create` ? I added the total output of the `rake routes` command above.